# I cannot access wifi in Windows 10, only ethernet is working now

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-registry, taskbar

I cannot access wifi settings anywhere in Windows10 like in

1. taskbar
2. [in settings page networking area is showing nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD8oK.png)
3. [Icon in taskbar is also disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zjmv.png)

First wifi was working and I can connect to a network whose credentials were saved (although cannot connect to new networks because unable to view network list in wifi icon/taskbar). From this, I know the network card is ok.

Tried many solutions but nothing worked

1. reinstalling drivers
2. some changes in the registry (available online)[useful changes](https://windowsreport.com/wifi-adapter-not-working-windows-10/#2)
3. enabling/disabling network card in the device manager

Although some services cannot be started and give an error like error:1608
tried many solutions online to get them started but not working.

[services which are not starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ePMS.png) and How to make it start.

Hint: Maybe there is something changed in the registry, but I am unable to fix it. Battery icon was not showing first but it gets fixed due to some registry
changes I made.

Comment: Can you provide specifics?  You made registry changes but don’t indicate what those changes were.  You suspect your issue is connected to new software but did not indicate what that software was.  If you do suspect this problem is caused by that software have you tried to remove the software.  All this information should be added to your question instead of a comment

Comment: Did you make sure WiFi is enabled in the BIOS? Have you checked the laptop’s WiFi button / switch?

Comment: @Ramhound, i am not sure whether it was due to some application, because I install many at that time. And the registry settings which I follow are are [link](https://windowsreport.com/wifi-adapter-not-working-windows-10/#2). I will edit it in the question.

Comment: @Appleoddity I have not change any settings in the bios. Wifi is working in ubuntu.

Comment: Does the windows device manager show the wifi adapter?  I am betting it will either be missing or have a yellow triangle.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas yes it is showing

Comment: Sorry @jaze.. then I got nothing.. :(  good luck.